# How to make a scrolling graph in Processing?

Tags: graph, arduino, processing

I have a LIDAR sensor hooked up to an Arduino Uno.

I am trying to replicate the graph shown in this short Youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lmS6h4_nmqM&t=13s&ab_channel=IanCole

I am having trouble:

1. Creating a real-time x-axes
2. Making the graph move with the data instead of having to wipe the slate clean every time

Could someone please guide me on how to fix my code?

Image of my progress so far:[Processing graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szZDc.png)

**Processing code:**

```
import processing.serial.*;

Serial myPort;        // The serial port
int xPos = 1;         // horizontal position of the graph
float inByte = 0;


void setup () {
  size(800, 700);
  myPort = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[0], 115200);
  myPort.bufferUntil('\n');
  background(0);
  smooth();
  drawStuff();
}

void draw () {
  translate(5, -100);
  stroke(255, 34, 255);
  line(xPos, height, xPos, height - inByte);
  smooth();
  if (xPos >= width){
  xPos = 0;
  translate(5, -100);
  background(0);
  drawStuff();
  }else{
      xPos++;
    }
}

void drawStuff() {
  background(0);
  for (int i = 0; i <= width; i += 25) {
    fill(0, 255, 0);
    text(i/2, i-10, height-15);
    stroke(0);
    line(i, height, i, 0);
  }
  for (int j = 0; j < height; j += 100) {
    fill(0, 255, 0);
    text(85-j/(height/100), 0, j);
    stroke(255);
    line(0, j, width, j);
  }
}

void serialEvent (Serial myPort) {
  String inString = myPort.readStringUntil('\n');

  if (inString != null) {
    inString = trim(inString);
    inByte = float(inString);
    println(inByte);
    inByte = map(inByte, 0, 1023, 0, height);
  }
}
```

**Arduino code:**

```
#include "Adafruit_VL53L0X.h"

Adafruit_VL53L0X lox = Adafruit_VL53L0X();

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  // wait until serial port opens for native USB devices
  while (! Serial) {
    delay(1);
  }
  
  Serial.println("Adafruit VL53L0X test");
  if (!lox.begin()) {
    Serial.println(F("Failed to boot VL53L0X"));
    while(1);
  }  
}


void loop() {
  VL53L0X_RangingMeasurementData_t measure;
    
  lox.rangingTest(&measure, false); // pass in 'true' to get debug data printout!

  if (measure.RangeStatus != 4) {  // phase failures have incorrect data
    Serial.println(measure.RangeMilliMeter);
  } else {
    Serial.println(" out of range ");
  }
    
  delay(100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend storing the values from your sensor in an array. It might look something like this:

```
float[] data = new float[50];

//... your code

void serialEvent (Serial myPort) {
  //...
  if (inString != null) {
    inString = trim(inString);
    inByte = float(inString);
    inByte = map(inByte, 0, 1023, 0, height);
    for (let i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
      data[i-1] = data[i];
    }
    data[data.length - 1] = inByte;
  }
}
```

What's happening here is you have an array of the past 50 outputs from the sensor, then you shift them all over (getting rid of the earliest one), then you put the new output as the last value in the array. You can then display these values on the graph however you desire.